# mongoose, how to record update_time in sub docs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I have a mongoose schema is:

[this is my mongoose schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WC7nO.png)

```
'use strict';

module.exports = app => {
const mongoose = app.mongoose;

const custSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  belong: { // 所属信息
    user_id: { type: 'String', required: true },
    type: { type: 'Number', required: true }, // bee、4s店、平台
    username: { type: 'String', required: true }, // 用户名
  },
  delete: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  info: { // 客户基本信息
    name: { type: 'String', required: true }, // 客户姓名
    brith: { type: 'Date', required: true }, // 出生日期
    sex: { type: 'Number', required: true }, // 性别
    eduction: Number, // 学历
    level: { type: 'Number', required: true }, // 客户等级
    tag: Number, // 客户标签
    tel: { type: 'Number', required: true }, // 电话
    family: { // 家庭信息
      situation: Number, // 家庭类型
      earning: Number, // 家庭总收入
      location: { // 家庭住址
        province: Number, // 省
        city: Number, // 市县
        region: Number, // 区镇
        addr: String, // 具体地址
      },
    },
    job: { // 工作信息
      industry: Number, // 行业
      company: String, // 公司
      occupation: String, // 职位
      earning: Number, // 收入
      location: { // 公司地址
        province: Number, // 省
        city: Number, // 市县
        region: Number, // 区镇
        addr: String, // 具体地址
      },
    },
    comment: String, // 备注
    update_time: { type: 'Date', required: false }, // 数据更新时间
  },
  ... other code
```

how to save update_time when I update a field in 'custSchema.info'?

such as: I want to update 'info.name', after that, a update_time in 'cust.schema.info' will be included.

I don't prefer to solve this question by add logic on Service, Can I solve it by defining schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can! Actually, this is a common issue, there are several plugins to help you, my recommendation is: Mongoose Timestamp.

https://github.com/drudge/mongoose-timestamp

It is very simple, a single file, you can actually read it before integrating into you project [directly on Github](https://github.com/drudge/mongoose-timestamp/blob/master/index.js).

Then, you can use the timestamps as follows:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({username: 'Prince'}, { password: 'goatcheese' }, { new: true, upsert: true })
        .exec(function (err, updated) {
            console.log(user.updatedAt); // Should be approximately createdAt + 1 second
            console.log(user.createdAt < user.updatedAt); // true
        });
```

Comment: thank you, this npm is useful ! But it can only resolve updating for partial field,  I want to save all this doc to update(cover old document).

Comment: because of many field need to be updated one time, i do not prefer to compare new doc with old.